# Reinstall MongoDB without deletion of database

Tags: database, mongodb, macos, homebrew

I'm dealing with MongoDB having a large database (~600GB) on macOS. After `mongodb` has been removed from homebrew-core, I'm no longer able to configure it or simply restart. After some research, I came to the conclusion that I need to reinstall `mongodb`. How can I reinstall it without the deletion of the database?

Comment: where is your DB hosted? Do you use an external DB server?

Comment: My DB hosted on macOS High Sierra. I don't use any external DB servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use brew to install MongoDB:

[Install MongoDB Community Edition on macOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)

Once it's installed, you can either:

- Change the dbpath in the config file in `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`, or
- Run `mongod --dbpath <the old database file path> ...`

Take care to ensure that you're installing *the same major version* of MongoDB. If previously you're running 3.6.x, don't install 4.0.x or 4.2.x or you'll risk data issues if you do this without following the proper [upgrade instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/).

Also recommended to take a backup of your dbpath before doing this.